# Some miss information of theorems in textbook - Rice

Tags: statistics

**Theorem A**
Under appropriate smoothness conditions on $f$, the mle from an i.i.d. sample is consistent.

*Question: What does the "appropriate smoothness conditions" mean exactly?*

**Lemma A**
Define $I(\theta)$ by
$$I(\theta)=E[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f(X|\theta)]^2$$Under appropriate smoothness conditions on $f$, $I(\theta)$ may also be expressed as$$I(\theta)=-E[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \log f(X|\theta)]$$
*Question: What does the "appropriate smoothness conditions" mean exactly?*

**Theorem B**
Under smoothness conditions on $f$, the probability distribution of $\sqrt{nI(\theta_0)}(\hat{\theta}-\theta_0)$ tends to a standard normal distribution.
*Question: What does the "smoothness conditions" mean exactly?*

Comment: At least regarding Lemma A: It's a hand wavy way of saying, assume what you need to about the differentiability of these function so that these expressions make sense (in the typical sense).  e.g. the first one requires the function is at least differentiable wrt $\theta$.

Comment: I guess the differentiability is a condition too strong?